# Replication SQL Server to a Cluster with error

Tags: replication, transactional-replication

I have a source DB MSSQL Server and deploy transactional-replication
 to a cluster with 2 Node(A&B).
The subscriber was added using SQL IP of Cluster and using "sa" account.
It run fine when server A active and server B passive.
When i shutdow the server A the replication stop and show error:

```
The process could not connect to Subscriber 'AHTDWHSQL'. (Source: 
 MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL0)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL0
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [1326].  
(Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1326)
Get help: http://help/1326
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1326)
Get help: http://help/1326
Login timeout expired (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: HYT00)
Get help: http://help/HYT00
```

Answer (score 0):

you got SQL Server error number "1326" which mean there is a connection issue to the destination server, how to troubleshoot that

1. ping the server and check if you can reach it, and connection allowed via firewall.
2. check if SQL Server services are up and running (you can do that from services window).
3. check if you can access the server remotely using SQL server, if not open SQL server configuration manager, choose "SQL Server Network Configuration", then "protocol for MSSQLSERVER", open TCP/IP, and make sure Sever allowing traffic to the destination.
4. Open SSMS, connect, right-click on the server, properties, connections, and check "Allow remote connections to this server". (you have to restart the service to make sure changes took effect).